# How to Convert unsigned char* to std::string in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, byte

I have `unsigned char*`, want to convert it to `std::string`. Can you please tell me the safest way to do this?

Comment: C++ doesn't have a byte type, so you need to tell us what the type actually is.

Comment: BYTE resolves to "unsigned char"

Comment: And what about `Byte`? And more importantly, what does you pointer point to? A single `Byte` value or an array of `Byte`? What do you want in your string: a textual representation of the value of the pointer or string that represents the values of the object(s) pointed to?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You just needed to cast the `unsigned char` into a `char` as the `string` class doesn't have a constructor that accepts `unsigned char`:

```
unsigned char* uc;
std::string s( reinterpret_cast< char const* >(uc) ) ;
```

However, you will need to use the length argument in the constructor if your byte array contains nulls, as if you don't, only part of the array will end up in the string (the array up to the first null)

```
size_t len;
unsigned char* uc;
std::string s( reinterpret_cast<char const*>(uc), len ) ;
```

Comment: BYTE * pbData = "SomeString"
size_t length = 10
I have the length before hand, so i used this :
I used this method, "std::string(reinterpret_cast<char *>(pbData), length );"

It works, but once in while i see crash in memcpy.
Tryint to find our why crash happened, though it seems working for me

Comment: As a portability pedant, I want to point out that this only works on systems with 2's complement arithmetic. On 1's complement or sign-magnitude architectures, it is not safe to reinterpret_cast between `char*` and `unsigned char*` (well, it's safe, but you'll get surprising results if  `char` is signed and any of the characters have the top bit set). In this case the questioner is obviously on Windows, so no problem.

Answer (score 10):

`BYTE*` is probably a typedef for `unsigned char*`, but I can't say for sure.  It would help if you tell us what `BYTE` is.

If BYTE* is unsigned char*, you can convert it to an std::string using the std::string range constructor, which will take two generic Iterators.

```
const BYTE* str1 = reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*> ("Hello World");
int len = strlen(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(str1));
std::string str2(str1, str1 + len);
```

That being said, are you sure this is a good idea?  If `BYTE` is `unsigned char` it may contain non-ASCII characters, which can include NULLs.  This will make `strlen` give an incorrect length.

Answer (score 5):

```
BYTE *str1 = "Hello World";
std::string str2((char *)str1);  /* construct on the stack */
```

Alternatively:

```
std::string *str3 = new std::string((char *)str1); /* construct on the heap */
cout << &str3;
delete str3;
```

Comment: It does not work, I get an error saying "'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::basic_string(const std::allocator<_Ty> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'BYTE *' to 'const std::allocator<_Ty> &'"

Comment: That's because `std::string` doesn't have a constructor that takes an `unsigned char*`, and so the compiler falls back on the templated constructor meant for allocators.  You need to either use `std::string(Iterator begin, Iterator end)`, or `std::string(const char*, std::size_t n)` and cast the BYTE* to a char*

Comment: `std::string &str3 = new ...`, didn't you mean `*` instead of `&`? And btw, creating std::string on the heap is usually bad idea and defeats half the purpose of having a string class with value semantics.

Comment: You're all right.  I hadn't run this through the compiler as I should have.  You will need the (char *) typecast, since std::string doesn't handle BYTE/unsigned char types.  And the reference example was wrong; it should have been a pointer.

Comment: This answer has lots of problems: C-style casts, using heap allocation for no reason, etc.

Answer (score 2):

BYTE is nothing but `typedef unsigned char BYTE;`

You can easily use any of below constructors

```
string ( const char * s, size_t n );
string ( const char * s );
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the complete code

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned char BYTE;

int main() {
  //method 1;
  std::vector<BYTE> data = {'H','E','L','L','O','1','2','3'};
  //string constructor accepts only const char
  std::string s((const char*)&(data[0]), data.size());
  std::cout << s << std::endl;

  //method 2
  std::string s2(data.begin(),data.end());
  std::cout << s2 << std::endl;

  //method 3
  std::string s3(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&data[0]), data.size()) ;
  std::cout << s3 << std::endl;
 
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If has access to CryptoPP

Readable Hex String to unsigned char

```
std::string& hexed = "C23412341324AB";
uint8_t      buffer[64] = {0};
StringSource ssk(hexed, true,
            new HexDecoder(new ArraySink(buffer,sizeof(buffer))));
```

And back

```
std::string hexed;
uint8_t val[32]  = {0};
StringSource ss(val, sizeof(val), true,new HexEncoder(new StringSink(hexed));
// val == buffer
```