# Convert uint8_t* to std::string in C++?

Tags: c++, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Convert Byte* to std::string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673445/how-to-convert-byte-to-stdstring-in-c)

I'm on an embedded device and try to receive a message.
This message is given by a `const uint8_t* data` and its length `size_t len`.

Now I need a `std::string` to output my data.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1673445/50079

Comment: Voting to reopen, since this is from `uint8_t` and the other is `char` which might be different on insane devices.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you don't want to convert the encoding, this will work:

```
std::string s( data, data+len );
```

If you want to convert UTF-8 into whatever system encoding is used by your platform, you need to use some platform-specific means.

Comment: Why is the second constructor argument `data+len`? Shouldn't it just be `len`?

Comment: @Ian: This calls the constructor taking two iterators. `data` is the begin iterator, and `data+len` is the end iterator.

Answer (score 1):

Is your `uint8*` string null-terminated?  If so, you can just do:

```
std::string mystring(data);
```

Comment: when there's a length, the data is probably not null-terminated

Comment: And it's probably better to explicitly specify it anyway; all that's going to do is search for the length again anyway.

Comment: Also you are assuming that there is no '\0' character inbedded in the string. The std::string does not put any special emphasis on the '\0' character.

Answer (score 0):

For some case sizeof(uint8) != sizeof(char), you could do:

```
std::string output( len, 0 );
for ( size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i )
  output[ i ] = static_cast<char>( data[ i ] );
```

Comment: `sizeof(uint8)!=sizeof(char)` is impossible. `sizeof` is in units of `char`, so if `char` is larger than 8 bits, there is no way to have an 8-bit type, i.e. `uint8` cannot exist.