# convert uint8_t array to string

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stdstring, unsigned-char, uint8t

I the project I have a struct that has one member of type `unsigned int array`(`uint8_t`) like below

```
typedef uint8_t  U8;
typedef struct {
    /* other members */
    U8 Data[8];
} Frame;
```

a pointer to a variable of type `Frame` is received that during debug I see it as below in console of VS2017

```
/* the function signatur */
void converter(Frame* frm){...}

frm->Data   0x20f1feb0 "6Ã¾x}\x1òà...   unsigned char[8] // in debug console
```

now I want to assign it to an 8byte string

I did it like below, but it concatenates the numeric values of the array and results in something like `"541951901201251242224"`

```
std::string temp;
for (unsigned char i : frm->Data)
{
    temp += std::to_string(i);
}
```

also tried `const std::string temp(reinterpret_cast<char*>(frm->Data, 8));` which throws exception

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1673536/2935386) reinterpret_cast should be to a `char const*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your original cast `const std::string temp(reinterpret_cast<char*>(frm->Data, 8));` you put the closing parenthesis in the wrong place, so that it ends up doing `reinterpret_cast<char*>(8)` and that is the cause of the crash.

Fix:

```
std::string temp(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(frm->Data), sizeof frm->Data);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, and as you have described my problem, I am accepting this.
finally, I asked a question in C++ that did not get downvotes at first place :))

Answer (score 0):

Just leave away the `std::to_string`. It converts numeric values to their string representation. So even if you give it a `char`, it will just cast that to an integer and convert it to the numerical representation of that integer instead. On the other hand, just adding a `char` to an `std::string` using `+=` works fine. Try this:

```
int main() {
    typedef uint8_t  U8;
    U8 Data[] = { 0x48, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x6C, 0x6F };
        std::string temp;
        for (unsigned char i : Data)
        {
            temp += i;
        }
        std::cout << temp << std::endl;
}
```

See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D) for more information and examples on `std::string`'s `+=` operator.